# Llenar una Clase con un ArrayList de Objetos de otra clase

Tags: java, combobox

Basicamente estoy diseñando un programa para un restaurant (sin stock), es para rendir la materia de programación. Solicito ayuda :(

Tengo una clase Insumo, otra clase Plato, y otra clase Mesa.

Se instancian Objetos de tipo Insumos con su código y descripción.
Los objetos clase Plato también tienen código y descripción, pero a su vez están compuestos por un ArrayList.
Los objetos de clase Mesa tienen su número identificador, y están compuestos por colecciones de Plato. 
Todos mis ArrayList (Insumos y Platos) se almacenan en una clase aparte, llamada Resto (para evitar que se pierdan).

Pero la clase Plato tiene su propio ArrayList de tipo Insumo, ya que cada instancia de Plato puede contener 1, o varios objetos de tipo .-

Lo que no me esta saliendo es enviar mediante la interfaz gráfica al ArrayList para meter dentro de la clase Plato.

Es decir... Conseguí levantar en un ComboBox el listado de Insumos que doy de alta. Lo que necesitaría es una opción para elegir varios Insumos, y agregarlos al ArrayList de la clase Plato. Para luego enviar ese objeto de tipo Plato a su ArrayList correspondiente, con el ArrayList que le corresponde.

Me explico?

Es decir, tendria un ArrayList que contendría objetos de tipo Plato y cada Plato tiene objetos tipo ArrayList.

Espero que se entienda... Cualquier cosa edito o pongo el código.

Comment: Me suena a que necesitas usar un checklist como el de [aquí](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/CheckListExample2.htm) o el de [este ejemplo](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5342) y luego solo pasar los objetos marcados/seleccionados como parte del otro objeto que deseas crear.

Comment: Estuve viendo esas soluciones... ¿Sería más practico utilizar un JList e insertar los objetos como elementos, y luego llamar al elemento indexado (InFocus o ElementIndex)? intentaré probar con esa solución (Ya he conseguido agregar mis elementos al JList y no me la quiero complicar demasiado, no tengo mucho tiempo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abrevia más las preguntas por favor. Más sencillo sería usar las clase con esta jerarquia:

Clase main

```
Mesa mesa = new Mesa ();
Plato plato = new Plato ();
Plato plato1 = new Plato ();
Plato plato2 = new Plato ();
mesa.get (0).addPlato (plato);
mesa.get (0).addPlato (plato2);
mesa.get (0).addPlato (plato3);
```

Clase mesa:
Añadir la funcionalidad de la variable plato el get, set y el add.

```
//declaración variable
private List <Plato> platos;
//instancia
plato = new ArrayList  <Plato>();
//función de add
public void addPlato (Plato arg){
   this.platos.add (arg);
}
```

Te dejo este tipo de estructura para que te sirva una forma simple y sencilla de trabajar con listas.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43809/discussion-on-answer-by-pablo-garcia-tamarit-llenar-una-clase-con-un-arraylist-d).